# 3 Divs side by side overflow one another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been chasing around this problem for hours, here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.controls{
    display: table;
    height: 10%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
}
#w1 {
    width:25%;
}
#can
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#canTwo{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;

}
textarea { 
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 1.25vw; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#w2{
    width:50%;
}
#w3{ 
    width:25%;
}

.controlbuttons {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="controls">
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w1"><canvas id = "can" width = "0" height = "0"></div>
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w2"><textarea rows="3" cols="50"></textarea></div>
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w3"><canvas id = "canTwo" width = "0" height = "0"></div>
</div>

</div>
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   fitToContainer();
});
var canvas = document.getElementById("can"),
    ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    canvasTwo = document.getElementById("canTwo"),
    ctxTwo    = canvasTwo.getContext('2d');
function fitToContainer(){

    var control = document.getElementsByClassName("controlbuttons")[0];
    var h = control.clientHeight;
    var w = control.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = h;

    canvas.width = w;

    canvasTwo.height = h;

    canvasTwo.width = w;

    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000);

    ctxTwo.fillStyle = "green";
    ctxTwo.fillRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000);


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ca3uw837/

Basically I have one textarea and it's width takes 50% of the page and it is exactly in the middle, there are two
canvases to it's side which take 25% width.
I am trying to get them to align perfectly(same height, exactly one next to the other) but here is how it looks on my pc:
[image]

What am I supposed to do? use flexbox? I am not sure I know how to achieve it as canvases are very tricky with their sizing technique. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: what determines the height of the canvas and the text area? The `controls` container ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align `table-cell` items to the top you should use: `vertical-align: top`. Both `canvas` are missing `height` and `width` property, set them to `100%`. Add `box-sizing: border-box` to the textarea:

**[box-sizing: border-box](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)**

> The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes
>   content, padding and border, but not the margin

So:

```
textarea {
  /** ... rest of styles ...*/
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.controlbuttons { vertical-align: top; } /* Align items to the top */
.controlbuttons canvas { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

**Demo:** (Tested in firefox 53.0.2 & Chrome 56.0.2924.87)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  fitToContainer();
});
var canvas = document.getElementById("can"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  canvasTwo = document.getElementById("canTwo"),
  ctxTwo = canvasTwo.getContext('2d');

function fitToContainer() {

  var control = document.getElementsByClassName("controlbuttons")[0];
  var h = control.clientHeight;
  var w = control.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = h;

  canvas.width = w;

  canvasTwo.height = h;

  canvasTwo.width = w;

  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000);

  ctxTwo.fillStyle = "green";
  ctxTwo.fillRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000);


}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.controls {
  display: table;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}

#w1 {
  width: 25%;
}

textarea {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
#w2 {
  width: 50%;
}
#w3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.controlbuttons {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  
}
.controlbuttons canvas {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>


  <div class="controls">
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w1">
      <canvas id="can" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
    </div>
   <div class="controlbuttons" id="w2">
      <textarea rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w3">
      <canvas id = "canTwo" width = "0" height = "0"></canvas>   
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what was the problem and what was the fix?

Answer (score 1):

Apply `flexbox` to `.controls` to align the child elements. Also apply `box-sizing: border-box` to `textbox` as the default padding adds with the 100% height of the textbox. `border-box` will make the padding inclusive of height.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  fitToContainer();
});
var canvas = document.getElementById("can"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  canvasTwo = document.getElementById("canTwo"),
  ctxTwo = canvasTwo.getContext('2d');

function fitToContainer() {

  var control = document.getElementsByClassName("controlbuttons")[0];
  var h = control.clientHeight;
  var w = control.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = h;

  canvas.width = w;

  canvasTwo.height = h;

  canvasTwo.width = w;

  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000);

  ctxTwo.fillStyle = "green";
  ctxTwo.fillRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000);


}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
}

#w1 {
  width: 25%;
}

#can float: left;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
top: 0;

}
#canTwo {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
}
textarea {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#w2 {
  width: 50%;
}
#w3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.controlbuttons {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <div class="controlbuttons" id="w1"><canvas id="can" width="0" height="0"></div>
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w2"><textarea rows="3" cols="50"></textarea></div>
    <div class="controlbuttons" id="w3"><canvas id = "canTwo" width = "0" height = "0"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what was the problem and what was the fix?

Comment: The textbox has a padding by default, which made it's effective size larger than the 100%; setting border-box makes sure the padding is restrained to the 100%: The flexbox was used to align the items. I removed table properties as tables should NOT be used for anything other than tabular data, specially NOT for styling and positioning